# Is there a way to add protection to cells that are being copy pasted in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have an issue with Google Sheets protection. I am using protect whole sheet except certain cells.

Let's say that I have 3 ranges that are protected within 6 Rows and 6 Columns.

(A23:B26, E24:E25, E27:E28)

So, I have a working macro where the user selects a cell and runs the macro.
The macro successfully copies 6 rows from the top and pastes them underneath.

Please see below the function, `AddRow()`.

When these 6 Rows are copied, I would like for the rows being copied and the new rows generated to keep their protection.
However, Google Sheets does not do this automatically.

So, what can I do to add new ranges into the protection of the sheet.

For example: The new ranges will be the original plus the copied cells.

{(A23:B26, E24:E25, E27:E28), (A30:B33, E31:E32, E34:E5)}

From my understanding, it shouldn't be an issue but it's not working for me.

AddRow() function is a working macro where the user selects a cell and runs the macro.
The macro successfully copies 6 rows from the top and pastes them in the selected cell.

```
function AddRow() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  if (spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue() == "AddRow")
  {
    sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() - 7, 1, 6, sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(7, 0).activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue("AddRow");
  }
};
```

I have seen and tried myself the protection macro, however, I am not sure how to get these ranges as well as that since this macro can run 100 times, I would like it to keep protection on the whole sheets except these ranges in those 600 Rows.

The protection code I have so far:

```
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  var protection = allProtections[0];
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-14, 0, 8, 6), spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-5, 0, 6, 6)]);
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(20, 0, 8, 6), spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(29, 0, 6, 6), spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(36, 0, 6, 6)]);
};
```

This is manually setting the protection and even then it's not working.

Essentially, I would like my macro to copy the rows, then go to sheet protection, add new ranges of cells (and keep the current protected ranges) and save the protection.

There is also something that can be used on a support page.

```
  var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges();
  var newRanges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    newRanges.push(sheet2.getRange(ranges[i].getA1Notation()));
  } 
  p2.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);
```

This code copies the protection on to another sheet.
In my case, I want it to happen on the same sheet but in different rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zS47CTanrhaYerzzxeBqSGozcM4YZPPyre1kt8YyEBQ/edit?usp=sharing

I have explained the problem in a better way here.

Comment: So, if I understood your question correctly you have a protected sheet that you are copying to and would like to allow anyone edit the copied cells. Is that right? Could you share a simple example to see exactly what you want? (I'll make a copy to work with, view edit are enough)

Comment: ok, will do, thank you.

Comment: @Marti Thank you for your help. I have explained it a lot better in the sheet. You have editor access. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zS47CTanrhaYerzzxeBqSGozcM4YZPPyre1kt8YyEBQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to be working for me even though I'm not 100% sure if it's what you want:

```js
function addPeriod() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  const currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()

  if (currentCell.getValue() === 'AddRow') {
    // Copy values
    const copySource = sheet.getRange(currentCell.getRow() - 6, 1, 6, sheet.getMaxColumns())
    copySource.copyTo(currentCell, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false)

    // Set protections exceptions
    const protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
    if (protections.length === 1) {
      const protection = protections[0]
      const exceptions = protection.getUnprotectedRanges()
      const unprotectRange = currentCell.offset(1, 0, 4, 1)
      protection.setUnprotectedRanges([...exceptions, unprotectRange])
    }


    // Prepare to be able to add next period
    const nextCell = currentCell.offset(6, 0)
    nextCell.setValue('AddRow')
    nextCell.activate()
  }
}
```

This code adds a new period and removes the protection from the colored ranges.

It's similar to what you have, but note that `setUnprotectedRanges(ranges)` is the list of all the ranges that should be unprotected. So you need to get the current list and add your at the end. I do that with the spread syntax (`[...exceptions, unprotectRange]`).

### References

- [Class Protection (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [Class Sheet (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Spread syntax (...) (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.